# Modifying a list inside iteration

Tags: java, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

We all know this is illegal and will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
for (Item i : theList) {
 if (i.num == 123)
  foo(i); // foo modifies theList
}
```

But what about this?

```
for (Item i : theList) {
 if (i.num == 123) {
  foo(i); // foo modifies theList
  break;
 }
}
```

Because the loop is broken before `theLists`'s iterator's `next` is called, there is no `ConcurrentModificationException`. But does that make it legal?

Comment: The first one is not illegal - `foo` doesn't change list but the properties of one item from the list at most. `foo(theList)` would have a chance to do illegal structural changes to the list.

Comment: Actually it does change the list, it removes i.

Comment: It's too complex and deep to completely paste here. Just assume that somewhere down the line it results in `theList.remove(i)` being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, I concluded that it has to be. The "solution" would be

```
for (Item i : theList) {
 if (i.num == 123) {
  theI = i;
  break;
 }
}
foo(theI);  // foo modifies theList
```

But in terms of how often `next` is called, that's exactly the same.

Comment: Again, you don't change "the list" (`theList`) but one element of the list which is allowed.